# Как на C# выполнить метод в "очереди" раз в секунду, а не чаще?

Tags: c#, очередь

Мне нужно, как только происходит определённое событие "Данные обновились"- запускать метод X -"Разослать обновлённые данные клиентам".
Но если событие вызывается, скажем 50 раз в секунду- нет необходимости столько же раз сразу же запускать метод X, создавая нагрузку.
Можно ли как-то поставить событие в очередь, и если очередь есть, запустить метод X- то выполнить только самое последнее событие?

---

Вариант 1: Есть 50 клиентов онлайн. Подключается 51-й. Я рассылаю 50+1 клиенту список клиентов онлайн. Подкл 52-й - делаем то же самое.
Вариант 2: Есть 50 клиентов онлайн. Подключается 51-й. Отсылаю так-же всё. Но тут подключается пара десятков человек и я должен так же всё рассылать.

Я хочу, если только что была рассылка- не отправлять сразу, а ждать, скажем, секунду и потом, если был запрос разослать данные- то сделать рассылку таблицы на текущий момент времени. Таким образом все клиенты получили данные- пусть не моментально, а на секунду позже, зато я не слал очень много раз.
Ну как-то так.
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Может быть использовать таймер?

Comment: @BlackWitcher не. Просто метод "Send" может запускаться очень редко. Но в первый момент включения  подключается клиент1- я отсылаю всем данные, потом клиент1000 например- тоесть я  должен разослать каждому! что подключился нов чел и кидаю обновлённую таблицу. А потом, например, вообще никто ничего не делает и смысла в таймере нет. Я просто может не правильно выразился, что я хочу(

Comment: Кажется я примерно понял о чем речь: первая аналогия, которая приходит на ум, это скайп, который оповещает (при соответствующих настройках), что кто-то из контакт листа появился в сети или изменил статус. Т.е., условно, если в 1 момент времени статус поменяли 3 человека из контакт-листа, то он уведомит меня об этом, если в другой момент времни поменялся статус у 10-рых, он уведомит о них. Ну а а если никто ничего не делает, то ничего и не меняется, я верно понял?

Comment: Почему бы не хранить дату последнего вызова события? Когда создается событие, проверяй послендню дату выполнения. Если ты видишь, что с момента последнего срабатывания события не прошло и секунды, делай Return.

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь Rx Extensions, вам подойдёт Throttle:         `Observable.FromEventPattern(eventSource, eventName).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0/50)).Subscribe(args => X());`

Comment: А еще в дополнение к комментарию @iluxa1810 - можно создать очередь из сообщений, что-то вроде буфера, условно, пусть на 10 событий. При добавлении нового события в буфер - проверять, не заполнен ли он? (тогда вызываем уже метод Send и чистим буфер). Ну и да, при этом смотреть, не прошла ли секунда с момента последнего вызова метода. Если прошла, и не одна, то всё равно вызываем Send для не полностью заполненного буфера.

Таким образом просто вместо генерации _каждого_ события об изменении данных - это будет делаться порциями, и при этом не будут теряться одиночные события.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал [Quartz .NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) - чрезвычайно гибкая настройка...

Comment: @kimaman2, nак это планировщик, т.е. суть таймер :) А он не подходит автору вопроса, вроде как.

Comment: @BlackWitcher ООооо.... Не до конца вник в суть вопроса) Тогда голос за твой комент....

Comment: Например 5-й клиент подключился. И вот подключается сразу же 6-й клиент, тоесть я должен сразу переслать обновлённую таблицу юзеров пяти клиентов (можно конечно пересылать,что подключился клиент такой-то, но я хочу сейчас именно всю таблицу  клиентов онлайн переслать). По обычной логике- будет слаться много сообщений, но если сделать так, что б метод рассылки заблокировался на отправку, скажем на секунду, как только он выполнился и имел счётчик запусков. Тоесть за следующую сек пришло 20 попыток разослать данные, а он молчит и потом отсылает актуальные данные

Comment: Эм... Пожалуйста, опишите задачку более полно, что там у вас происходит, как вы хотите, что бы было, и как планируете это реализовать, а то в угадайку играем. Например, если у вас 1000 клиентов, то вы будете рассылать сведения о этой тысяче всем 1000 клиентам? И вот про буфер что бы "молчал, а потом рассылал" я говорил выше. А с учетом привязки ко времени, как предложено в ответе - на первый взгляд решает задачку. Или я не очень прав?

Comment: @BlackWitcher обновил вопрос

Answer (score 6):

Ну, вы можете завести таймер и добавить в него немного логики.

Вот пример:

```
class Program
{
    public static event EventHandler NewClientArrived;
    static void X() => Console.WriteLine("\n\tSending notifications");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000) { AutoReset = false };
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, timerargs) => X();
        NewClientArrived += (sender, eventargs) => { if (!timer.Enabled) timer.Start(); };

        // запускаем симуляцию прихода клиентов
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            NewClientArrived(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Если вы используете RX Extensions, можно попробовать так:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Observable.FromEventPattern(typeof(Program), nameof(NewClientArrived))
                   .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                   .Subscribe(_ => X()))
        {
            // запускаем симуляцию прихода клиентов
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
                NewClientArrived(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно хранить дату последнего срабатывания события. Когда возбуждается событие, проверяй последний дату выполнения.

Если ты видишь, что с момента последнего срабатывания события не прошло и секунды, делай return.

Comment: Например 5-й клиент подключился. И вот подключается сразу же 6-й клиент, тоесть я должен сразу переслать обновлённую таблицу юзеров пяти клиентов (можно конечно пересылать,что подключился клиент такой-то, но я хочу сейчас именно всю таблицу  клиентов онлайн переслать). По обычной логике- будет слаться много сообщений, но если сделать так, что б метод рассылки заблокировался на отправку, скажем на секунду, как только он выполнился и имел счётчик запусков. Тоесть за следующую сек пришло 20 попыток разослать данные, а он молчит и потом отсылает актуальные данные