# Исключить частые вызовы метода с помощью костыля

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, tpl

Хочу исключить частые вызовы одного и того же метода. Вот, сделал костыль, хочу посоветоваться, хорошо ли он сделан.

Понимаю, что костыль это не хорошо. Тем не менее, на данный момент это лучше, чем ничего.

---

Например, есть следующий кусок кода (в реале будет *WPF*):

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        for (int i=0; i<=100; i++)
        {
            myClass.IncreaseCount();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(myClass.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Идея в том, чтобы `IncreaseCount()` вызвался не 100 раз, а не более 1 раза, скажем, за 50 милисекунд.

Вот моя реализация. Буду рад, если посоветуете, хорошая ли она или нет. И что в ней не хорошее.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Count { get; private set; } = 0;
    public void IncreaseCount()
    {
        ExecuteOnce(() => Count++);
    }

    private static bool IsConsecutiveCall = false;
    private static object SyncObject = new object();

    private void ExecuteOnce(Action codeBlock, int milliseconds = 50)
    {
        lock (SyncObject)
        {
            if (!IsConsecutiveCall)
            {
                codeBlock();
                var task = new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(milliseconds));

                //Edit
                task.ContinueWith(t => IsConsecutiveCall = false);
                /*
                //Before edit
                task.ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                        SynchronizationContext.Current.Send(s => IsConsecutiveCall = false, null);
                    }
                    );
                */
                IsConsecutiveCall = true;
                task.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А какая ваша настоящая цель? Ограничить количество обновлений UI?

Comment: Потому что для этого вам нужен скорее Rx Throttle

Comment: @VladD,сасибо, попробую разобраться как для метода делать (для event и yield+IEnumerable вроде понятно)

Comment: Вот вам пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581209/10105

Comment: `new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(milliseconds));` - ой, жесть... `Task.Delay` для кого сделан?